# What is the purpose of the Namespace element in cd_storage_conf.xml

Tags: content-delivery, configuration, web8.5

In the `cd_storage_conf.xml` configuration files, there is a namespace element.

```
<Namespace default="${namespaceprefix:-tcm}" />
```

What is it's purpose? Under what circumstances would one wish to change it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may want to change it if you're not using TCM as the source content management system for Content Delivery.

This is not yet a thing, but very soon it will be.